# How to render a NotFound page for all the nested routes in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using React Router DOM v6, the latest version as of 2022.

I have multiple files and layer of folders in my code:

```
.
└── src/
    └── routes/
        └── Users/
            ├── ViewUser/
            │   └── ViewUserRoutes.js
            └── UserRoutes.js
```

**UserRoutes.js:**

```js
import PageNotFound from '../../components/PageNotFound'
import ViewUserRoutes from './ViewUser/ViewUserRoutes.js'

export default function UserRoutes(){
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<AllUsers />}/>
      <Route path="/:id/*" element={<ViewUserRoutes />}/>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/>  {/*  here */}
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

**ViewUserRoutes.js:**

```js
import PageNotFound from '../../../components/PageNotFound'

export default function UserRoutes(){
  return(
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<ViewUserById />}/>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/> {/*  here */}
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

I want to render a `<PageNotFound />` component when the user navigates to a page not defined in any of my routes.

What I'm doing here, is that whenever I define a new `<Routes />`, I will to explicitly define a route called `<Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />`. Which is kind-a annoying and makes me feel wrong.

Isn't there something simple as:

**index.js**

```
<BrowserRouter fallback={<PageNotFound />}> {/*  something simple like this */}
  <Route path="users/*" element={<UserRoutes />} />
  {/* ... etc ...etc  */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

Or do I have to repeat that line of code every time I create a new resource in my app?

---

## Update: 18 Oct 2022.

I have tried the following:

**UserRoutes.js:**

```js
return(
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AllUsers />}/>  
    <Route path="/:id/*">
      <ViewUserRoutes /> {/*  here */}
    </Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/>  
  </Routes>
)
```

**ViewUserRoutes.js:**

```js
return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route path="/" element={<ViewUserById />}/>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/> {/*  here */}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
```

I can see the following error:
[image]

But I am using **React.Fragment** exactly like what the error is saying.

I have also tried the following:
**UserRoutes.js:**

```js
return(
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<AllUsers />}/>  
    <Route path="/:id/*" element={<ViewUserRoutes />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/>  
  </Routes>
)
```

**ViewUserRoutes.js:**

```js
return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route path="/" element={<ViewUserById />}/>
      <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound/>}/> {/*  here */}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
```

and I can see the following error:

[image]

The goal is, I don't want to define all the routes of my app in one file, because it would make the file where I define the routes too long, and complex to read and figure out the bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm doing here, is that whenever I define a new , I
> will to explicitly define a route called `<Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />`. Which is kind-a annoying and makes me
> feel wrong.

I don't disagree that it can feel annoying, or perhaps less ***DRY***, but it's by design. Each `Routes` component is matching its `Route` children against the URL path and the derived path to itself, so each needs to render a "catch all" route for anything they don't handle at their level.

> Or do I have to repeat that line of code every time I create a new
> resource in my app?

Yes, basically. Each `Routes` component handles its own matching. Keep in mind that while the route JSX may look the same, it's not actually a duplicate route.

If you want to avoid needing to render duplicate `PageNotFound` components you can use a single routing configuration with nested routes instead of the split configuration with descendent routes.

Example:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<AllUsers />} />
  <Route path="/:id">
    <Route index element={<ViewUserRoutes />} />
    <Route path="foo" element={<ViewUserRoutes />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
</Routes>
```

If user attempts to navigate to `"/1234/bar"` there isn't a route that matches other than the catch-all that renders the `<PageNotFound />`.

Comment: Can I use `<Route>` inside `<Route>` ? Or is it `<Route>` inside `<Routes>`?

Comment: @Normal Either. The `Route` component can only be rendered as a child of either the `Routes` component or another `Route` component in the case of nested routes. There's a bit of "magic" here where any `Route` component without an `element` prop renders an [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) by default for nested routes to render their matched content into. See [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets).

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply, I tried to place `<Route>` inside of another `<Route>` and I saw the following error in the console https://i.ibb.co/HtvXF2w/Screenshot-from-2022-10-17-15-44-17.png

Comment: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.

Comment: Actually at first I thought that, it's okay, no problem, I will repeat that PageNotFound route everywhere, however, the problem is not in the code repeating itself, but the actual problem is in the results, now when a user navigates to a not found page, ex: `/pos/jskdvbjkvsd` this will result in rendering the not found page within the wireframe which is not what I want, I want to render the entire page with the not found component, the routing nesting is cool, but there must a way to handle the not found page out of that as well.

Comment: see this screenshot which demonstrates the problem https://i.ibb.co/Zg6ytVS/Screenshot-from-2022-10-17-16-05-50.png

Comment: @Normal Sounds like (1) the code is rendering a `Route` component directly somewhere *not* as a child of a `Routes` or `Route` component, and (2) what you describe sounds like you want to render your app routes into a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) and the "not found" route *outside* the layout so it's "standalone" content.

Comment: Hello Drew, I have updated my question ,see above

Comment: for (1), I'm not sure, so I updated the question, but for (2), ... yes. but if it's hard to accomplish, it's not a problem, actually rendering the not found page inside the dashboard application layout is not a bad idea it looks beautiful.

Comment: @Normal It's best to create new SO posts instead of editing already answered and accepted posts as doing so can potentially invalidate existing answers. That said, in your 10-18-2022 update the `<Route path="/:id/*" element={<ViewUserRoutes />} />` route in UserRoutes.js is the correct syntax. If you ***don't*** want to render `NotFound` inside the user routes (*because layout*) then render a redirect instead to a "garbage" route, i.e. `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/404" replace />} />`, so the outer/root `NotFound` route component is rendered.